# Custom post type taxonomy template and URL confusion

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I have a custom post type called `case_study`. The custom taxonomy that's directly related to it is called `case_study_categories`. My code is below.

I created a custom taxonomy page called `taxonomy-case_study_categories.php`. However, I can't access the page if I go to something like example.com/case_study_categories.

I have the rewrite rules as the last function too. Any thoughts?

```
function cpt_case_study() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Case Studies', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Case Study', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Case Study', 'text_domain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Case Study', 'text_domain' ),
        'archives'              => __( 'Case Study Archives', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Case Study:', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Case Studies', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Case Study', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Case Study', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Case Study', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Update Case Study', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Case Study', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Case Studies', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
        'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'text_domain' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into Case Study', 'text_domain' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this Case Study', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list'            => __( 'Case Study list', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Case Study list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter Case Study list', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'Case Study', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'           => __( 'Case Studies', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( ),
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'case_study_categories' ),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 25,
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,        
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'page',
    );
    register_post_type( 'case_study', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'cpt_case_study', 0 );

function tax_case_study() {  
    register_taxonomy(  
        'case_study_categories',    //The name of the taxonomy. Name should be in slug form (must not contain capital letters or spaces). 
        'case_study',                       //post type name
        array(  
            'hierarchical' => true,  
            'label' => 'Case Study Categories',  //Display name
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'case_study/%case_studies%', // This controls the base slug that will display before each term
                'with_front' => false // Don't display the category base before 
            )
        )  
    );  
}  
add_action( 'init', 'tax_case_study');

function filter_post_type_link($link, $post){
    if ($post->post_type != 'case_study')
        return $link;

    if ($cats = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'case_study_categories'))
        $link = str_replace('%case_study_categories%', array_pop($cats)->slug, $link);
    return $link;
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'filter_post_type_link', 10, 2);
```

UPDATE: If I set the permalinks to plain (?case_study_categories=xyz) that works. However, when I switch back my permalinks to `/%category%/%postname%/` that doesn't work. I get 404's.

Comment: Taxonomies as a whole don't have archives, individual taxonomy *terms* have archives. I also think you're confusing the taxonomy and post type slugs, your tax slug should probably be just `case_study`. Your `post_type_link` function replaces a non-existent placeholder, you don't define your post type rewrite slug anywhere.

Comment: So I edited my code and changed the rewrite slug to case_study. Then the post_type_link I changed to just %case_study%. Then I changed my permalinks to /%category%/%postname%/. Still 404ing on the url: /case_study/resources-energy/Thoughts?